# Issue while making "vue-tel-input" component reusable with Vue 3, Vite, Composition API, and TS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-tel-input

I am using an NPM package, [vue-tel-input](https://vuejsexamples.com/international-telephone-input-with-vue/). I created a separate component for that, like-

**components/NPMPackages/VueTelInput/Index.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { VueTelInput } from 'vue-tel-input';
import 'vue-tel-input/vue-tel-input.css';

defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
<template>
  <VueTelInput
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  >
  </VueTelInput>
</template>
```

Now, I am importing this component inside my `App.vue`, like this-

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import NPMPackageVueTelInput from '@/components/NPMPackages/VueTelInput/Index.vue'

const phone = ref('');
</script>

<template>
  <NPMPackageVueTelInput v-model="phone"></NPMPackageVueTelInput>
</template>
```

But this code is not working. I am not able to type inside the input box, nothing is displaying.

Here is the [types-definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/vue-tel-input/index.d.ts) for this package.

I am using the following environment-

```
Vue- 3.3.4
vite - 4.4.9
typescript - 5.1.6
```

**If I do not make a common component, and use `vue-tel-input` directly inside `App.vue`, it works fine.**

Any help would be great.

Comment: make sure your phone variable has the correct type - `const phone = ref<string>('');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `value` in this line:

```js
@input="value => emit('update:modelValue', value)"
```

will return an `InputEvent` object, that's why you get that warning.

but I wrote your component in another way (it's not best practice but it works)
I apologize for my messy code

here is my solution:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch, onMounted } from "vue";
import { VueTelInput } from "vue-tel-input";
import "vue-tel-input/vue-tel-input.css";

// Props
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: String,
});

// Events
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

// Local State
const value = ref("");

// watch for change Local State
watch(value, (val) => {
  emit("update:modelValue", val);
});

// watch for change Props
watch(
  () => props.modelValue,
  (val) => {
    value.value = val;
  }
);

// set initial value
onMounted(() => {
  value.value = props.modelValue;
});
</script>

<template>
  <VueTelInput v-model="value"> </VueTelInput>
</template>
```

## Update

you can install `@vueuse/core` package and then use `useVModel` hook

here is the modified code with this method:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useVModel } from '@vueuse/core'
import { VueTelInput } from "vue-tel-input";
import "vue-tel-input/vue-tel-input.css";

const props = defineProps<{modelValue: string}>()
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
const data = useVModel(props, 'modelValue', emit)

</script>

<template>
  <VueTelInput v-model="data"> </VueTelInput>
</template>
```

Reference: [useVModel](https://vueuse.org/core/useVModel/) - [@vueuse/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vueuse/core)

Comment: Thanks much for the answer. I understood your approach too but as you said its a bit confusing approach using watcher and local variables. The concern is why the above example is not working. Do you have any kind of suspect about that?

Comment: I updated my answer in a simpler way I hope it helps (If you don't have any other child in your wrapper component, without any extra configuration the `v-model` will work but if you have more than one child in the component you should use one of those methods)